# Parsing XML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xmlhttprequest

I've used this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://domain.com/languages.php",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: xmlParser
   });
});

function xmlParser(xml) {
  $('#load').fadeOut();
  $(xml).find("result").each(function () {

  $(".main").append('' + $(this).find("language").text() + '');
  $(".lang").fadeIn(1000);

  });
}
```

I used a local XML file on my computer, it works fine, but when I change the URL to an website, it just keeps loading all the time...

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

There are restrictions on cross-domain requests. In particular, if you want to query domain.com, this page itself should be on domain.com (http://domain.com/my_page.html). You can't query domain.com from localhost or your file system (although, there are tricks for that).

**edit**
This hack is very easy and worked for me. But you, obviously, can't use it to query localhost.
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

You have to proxy the xml via some script on your site.

For example *getxml.php*:

```
<?php

 if(isset($_GET['q']) && isAjax())
 {
    $q = strip_tags($_GET['q']);
    header("Status: 200");
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    echo  file_get_contents($q,0);   
    exit();
 }

function isAjax() {
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
    ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'));
}
?>
```

Then, you'd modify your url to:
`url: "http://mysite.com/getxml.php?q=http://domain.com/languages.php"`

I'm not sure of any security implications with only checking the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH, so you may need to add more security there to check for ajax, but this does work as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restricts what you can grab from other sites. If you can, download the XML file, save it to your domain, and then work your magic with jQuery. I've done this a number of times (best to automate it with cURL/wget and a cron job). Or use something like SimplePie.

Note, sub.domain.com and domain.com are considered different domains, too.